# ConTeXt: use chapter headings in a column set

Tags: context, columns, context-lmtx

I recently started to use the column sets `\startcolumnset[TwoColumns]` in a document. But in combination with chapter headings.

I failed to restrict the start of the column lines below to the second line after the heading. The second column starts at the top with the grid.

The set seems to use the whole page (probably for the intended full page column layouts as shown in column set manual at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Columns#Column_Sets).
Any recommendations to fix this layout?

[image]

A minimal example:

```
% Common
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]
\enableregime[utf]

%Layout
\setuplayout[location=middle,
    marking=on,
    grid=yes,
    height=fit,
    width=fit]

\showgrid

% Typography
\setupbodyfont[mainface,rm,9pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=13pt]

% Headings
\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][
    page=yes,
    style={\bfc},
    before={\blank[line]},
    after={\blank[line]},
    width=\textwidth
]

% Columns
\definecolumnset[TwoColumns][n=2]

\starttext

\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Places]

    \startcolumnset[TwoColumns]
        \startlines
            \dorecurse{5}{Punxsutawney\par}
        \stoplines
        \column
        \startlines
            \dorecurse{5}{New York\par}
        \stoplines
    \stopcolumnset

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe playing with the header command, with framed and "location=high"
But you may have to increase a little bit the "setupinterlinespace" value (to provide some place to the headline).

```
% Common
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]
\enableregime[utf]

%Layout
\setuplayout[location=middle,
    marking=on,
    grid=yes,
    height=fit,
    width=fit]

\showgrid

% Typography
\setupbodyfont[mainface,rm,9pt]

% Headings

\setupinterlinespace[line=15pt]

\define[2]\MyChapter{\framed[frame=off,offset=0mm,location=high]{#2}}

\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][
    page=yes,
    style={\bfc},
    before={\blank[line]},
    after={\blank[line]},
%     width=\textwidth,
    command=\MyChapter,
]

% Columns
\definecolumnset[TwoColumns][n=2]
\definegridsnapping[first]

\starttext

\stopchapter


\startchapter[title=Places]

    \startcolumnset[TwoColumns]
        \startlines
            \dorecurse{5}{Punxsutawney\par}
        \stoplines
        \column
        \startlines
            \dorecurse{5}{New York\par}
        \stoplines
    \stopcolumnset

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!